# A quiz question related to contour integration i am unable to solve

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying quiz questions of last year in Complex analysis by myself and I was unable to solve this particular problem .

Adding it's image:
[image]

> I tried by putting z= 3$e^{it}$ and then changing limits from 0 to 2π  but I am not able to simplify the integral so as to solve integral to get an answer.

Please help.

Comment: Each have one singularity in the contour. What does the residue theorem state? How do you calculate residues? If you can answer those questions than you should be able to solve both integrals and thus solve for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know Residue Theorem. It is quite easy to evaluate the two sides using this theorem and you get the values of the two sides as $2 \pi i \lambda$ and $2 \pi i (-\frac  1 3)$. Hence (A) is the right answer.

Comment: Ya, I solved it without looking at your answer. But , anyway thanks!!